# What is the definition of the abelian group denoted by $\mathbb{Q}^*$ with $\times$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

My text states that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ with $\times$ is an abelian group.

I am unable to locate the definition of the set $\mathbb{Q}^*$. That is, I cannot find the definition of Q star, maybe because it is difficult to search for this notation.

This occurs in item (iv) of the first example at https://dec41.user.srcf.net/h/IA_M/groups/1_1.

It occured to be this may relate to the the non-zero rationals or some subset of the quaternions, but I cannot find a definition of this notation.

Comment: It is the group of units, i.e., of invertible elements. Since in a field $K$, every nonzero element is invertible, we have $K^{\ast}=K\setminus 0$. And it is a multiplicative group, so with the multiplication given in the field.

Comment: The underlying set is the set of non-zero rationals.  The product is ordinary multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any ring $R$ the notation $R^{\times}$ or $R^{\ast}$ usually denotes the group of units i.e. all those $x \in R$ s.t. $\exists y \in R: xy = 1$.

In the case of $\mathbb{Q}$ this is just $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that $\mathbb{Q}^\star$ is the set of all nonzero rational numbers.

$\mathbb{Q}^* = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Q/Non-Zero_Rational_Numbers